# How can I display image of dynamic field in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new to learning Drupal 8.

I need your help in how can i display dynamic images using Twig template. Also I have tried with below syntax.

```
{{ file_url(market.getFieldCollectionItem().field_turnpike_image.entity.uri.value|e) }}
{{ file_url(media.entity.field_image.entity.uri.value) }}
```

Using above syntax I could not display images using in twig template. Also with this syntax I have got some errors.

Please any one help me out to how can i display images using twig template.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following snippet to get the image if you are in `node twig template`

```
{{ file_url(node.field_image['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}
```

even

```
 {{ node.field_image.entity.url }}
```

Comment: @RavinaMadhani you're welcome :), dont forget to mark as accepted please to lead other guys that this is working